# displaying cdata in XML to be rendered as html

Tags: java, html, xml, cdata

I know that something similar has been asked many times but I cannot find a solution that works in my situation.

I'm generating CData section within an XML using java (StringBuffer) and I'm putting a simple HTML code as shown below:

```
   public String createXML(OrderDetailBean orderBean) throws ParserConfigurationException {
        logger.info("Starting to Create the XML");
        getConnectionProperties(); //Load properties file and set the Connection parameters 

        // Create document
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.newDocument();

        //Configuring the Factory to get a validating parser (ie one that understands name and spaces)
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true); 
        dbf.setValidating(true); 

        //Create doc type
        DOMImplementation domImpl = doc.getImplementation();
        DocumentType doctype = domImpl.createDocumentType("paymentService", "-//CompanyName//DTD CompanyName PaymentService v1//EN", "http://dtd.CompanyName.com/Service_v1.dtd");
        doc.appendChild(doctype);

        /******** Add ROOT element: PaymentService ********/
        Element rootElement = doc.createElement("paymentService");              
        //Add Attributes to the Root Element
        rootElement.setAttribute("version", "1.4");
        rootElement.setAttribute("Code", Code);

        /******** Add first element: submit ********/
        Element elementSubmit = doc.createElement("submit");

        /******** Add second element: order *******/
        Element elementOrder = doc.createElement("order");
        elementOrder.setAttribute("orderCode", ""+System.currentTimeMillis());

        // Add THIRD child element for CData 
        Element elementOrderContent = doc.createElement("orderContent");    
        StringBuffer orderContent = new StringBuffer();
        orderContent.append("<![CDATA[<center><table> <tr><td class=\"one width190\" align=\"left\" valign=\"top\">");
        orderContent.append("<span style=\" font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; color: #002469;\">");
        orderContent.append("Product:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><tr><td class=\"one\" align=\"left\" valign=\"top\"><span style=\" font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; color: #002469;\">");       
        orderContent.append("<strong>Product title</strong></span></td></tr> </table></center>]]>");
        logger.info("The orderContent Element in XML : "+orderContent.toString());
        Text orderContentText = doc.createTextNode(orderContent.toString());    
        logger.debug("Converted Text for Order Content is: "+orderContentText);
        elementOrderContent.appendChild(orderContentText);

        elementOrder.appendChild(elementOrderContent); //Add third Order Child: OrderContent

        elementSubmit.appendChild(elementOrder); //Add Order Element to Submit
        rootElement.appendChild(elementSubmit); //Add First Element (Submit) to Root Element (PaymentService)

        doc.appendChild(rootElement); //Add Root Element to XML Doc

        String stringXML = convertDocintoString(doc);  //print the XML to File      
        logger.info("The XML Generated is:  " + stringXML);
        return stringXML;
    }
```

This part is fine. I'm then converting that XML(XML Document) into String using XMLSerializer as shown below:

```
/*
     * Convert the XML Document into a String: Serialize DOM Document to generate the xml String 
     */
    public String convertDocintoString(Document doc) {
        logger.info("Converting the XML Document into String XML");
        //OutputFormat format = new OutputFormat(doc);
        OutputFormat format = new OutputFormat(doc, "UTF-8", true);
        //format.setIndenting(true);        
        XMLSerializer serializer;
        String outXML = null;

        try {
            StringWriter stringOut = new StringWriter ();
            serializer = new XMLSerializer(stringOut, format);
            serializer.asDOMSerializer();
            serializer.serialize(doc);
            outXML = stringOut.toString();
            logger.debug("The XML String IS: " + outXML);
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.debug("XML Document Not Found for Serialization!", e);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.debug((new StringBuilder("Issues when converting the XML Document into String XML")).append(e).toString());
        }
        return outXML;
    }
```

Here in this step above, I noticed that all the '<' and '>' tags get replaced by `&lt;` and `&gt;`. But I believe that this is normal.

Now when I'm trying to display that CData block in an HTML page, that CData block is being rendered as actual text rather than the actual HTML ie exactly as first code block that I pasted above.Can somebody please suggest whats happening here and what am I doing wrong? The HTML output is:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <META http-equiv='Pragma' content='no-cache'>
  <META http-equiv='Expires' content='0'>
  <title>Select Method</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen"> @import url(/pictures/dispatcher.css);</style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/jsp/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body >

    <div id="ordercontainer"><font ><b>Your Details</b></font>
    <br/><font >&lt;![CDATA[&lt;input type=&quot;hidden&quot; name=&quot;MC_mycustomvar&quot; value=&quot;M_ and MC_ combined&quot;&gt;&lt;center&gt;&lt;table&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td class=&quot;one width190&quot; align=&quot;left&quot; valign=&quot;top&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; color: #002469;&quot;&gt;Product:&lt;/span&gt;&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td class=&quot;one&quot; align=&quot;left&quot; valign=&quot;top&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; color: #002469;&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Product title&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&lt;/center&gt;]]&gt;</font><br/>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please let us know how you incorporated the `CDATA` section into the HTML. Post the HTML snippet after the section has been replaced and the code that performs the replacement.

Comment: Actually, also include the surrounding XML after serialization.

Comment: As CDATA segments have special meaning for XMLparsers, they hardly have any effect on HTML. Different HTML parser will treat it differently. You should remove CDATA before feeding it to any html

Comment: @Deepak, as requested I've added snippets of my code for more illustration. thx

Comment: Hi, Can anybody please help me here!! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the method [org.w3c.dom.Document.createCDATASection(String data)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#createCDATASection%28java.lang.String%29)

Anything you pass in the data parameter should be wrapped in CDATA in the resulting node.

```
    // Add THIRD child element for CData 
    Element elementOrderContent = doc.createElement("orderContent");    
    StringBuffer orderContent = new StringBuffer();
    // Note: Removed the <![CDATA[ ]]> from this string concat
    orderContent.append("<center><table> <tr><td class=\"one width190\" align=\"left\" valign=\"top\">");
    orderContent.append("<span style=\" font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; color: #002469;\">");
    orderContent.append("Product:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><tr><td class=\"one\" align=\"left\" valign=\"top\"><span style=\" font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; color: #002469;\">");       
    orderContent.append("<strong>Product title</strong></span></td></tr> </table></center>");
    logger.info("The orderContent Element in XML : "+orderContent.toString());
    // HERE IS THE UPDATED LINE
    Text orderContentText = doc.createCDATASection(orderContent.toString());    
    logger.debug("Converted Text for Order Content is: "+orderContentText);
    elementOrderContent.appendChild(orderContentText);

    elementOrder.appendChild(elementOrderContent); //Add third Order Child: OrderContent
```